# How to get the logged user's email address with Graph Request in Facebook Android sdk 4.0

Tags: android, facebook, facebook-graph-api, facebook-sdk-4.0

I'm trying to get the user's email address once he's logged into my Android app with Facebook (sdk 4.0). I've read many posts asking the same thing but I still couldn't make it work. I simply log the user in with the code

```
LoginManager.getInstance().logInWithReadPermissions(this, Arrays.asList("public_profile", "user_friends", "email"));
```

Then I make the Graph API request with

```
LoginManager.getInstance().registerCallback(fbCallbackManager,
            new FacebookCallback<LoginResult>() {
                @Override
                public void onSuccess(LoginResult loginResult) {
                    System.out.println(loginResult.getAccessToken().toString());

                    GraphRequest request = GraphRequest.newMeRequest(
                            loginResult.getAccessToken(),
                            new GraphRequest.GraphJSONObjectCallback() {
                                @Override
                                public void onCompleted(
                                        JSONObject object,
                                        GraphResponse response) {
                                    System.out.println(object.toString());

                                }
                            });
                    Bundle parameters = new Bundle();
                    parameters.putString("fields", "email");
                    request.setParameters(parameters);
                    request.executeAsync();
                }

                @Override
                public void onCancel() {
                    // App code
                }

                @Override
                public void onError(FacebookException exception) {
                    // App code
                }
            });
```

The output is just

```
{AccessToken token:ACCESS_TOKEN_REMOVED permissions:[public_profile, contact_email, user_friends, email, basic_info]}
{"id":"xxxxxxxxxxxxxxx"}
```

Even if I remove the "fields" part, I get a JSON with a bunch of the user's public info, but never the email field. I'm testing this on my own Facebook account, and I do have an email address associated to it.

Comment: did you find an answer for your question? If yes then please post it here as an answer.

Comment: Actually the code in ur question worked for me above all the answers below , thanks man

Answer (score 15):

Here is the complete code through which i get all the data we need from facebook

```
 login_facebook_button = (LoginButton) findViewById(R.id.login_facebook_button);
    login_facebook_button.setReadPermissions(Arrays.asList("public_profile", "user_friends", "email", "user_birthday"));
    //LoginManager.getInstance().logInWithReadPermissions(this, Arrays.asList("public_profile", "user_friends"));
    // Callback registration
    login_facebook_button.registerCallback(callbackManager, new FacebookCallback<LoginResult>() {
        @Override
        public void onSuccess(LoginResult loginResult) {
            // App code
            Log.e("onSuccess", "--------" + loginResult.getAccessToken());
            Log.e("Token", "--------" + loginResult.getAccessToken().getToken());
            Log.e("Permision", "--------" + loginResult.getRecentlyGrantedPermissions());
            Profile profile = Profile.getCurrentProfile();
            Log.e("ProfileDataNameF", "--" + profile.getFirstName());
            Log.e("ProfileDataNameL", "--" + profile.getLastName());

            Log.e("Image URI", "--" + profile.getLinkUri());

            Log.e("OnGraph", "------------------------");
            GraphRequest request = GraphRequest.newMeRequest(
                    loginResult.getAccessToken(),
                    new GraphRequest.GraphJSONObjectCallback() {
                        @Override
                        public void onCompleted(
                                JSONObject object,
                                GraphResponse response) {
                            // Application code
                            Log.e("GraphResponse", "-------------" + response.toString());
                        }
                    });
            Bundle parameters = new Bundle();
            parameters.putString("fields", "id,name,link,gender,birthday,email");
            request.setParameters(parameters);
            request.executeAsync();

        }

        @Override
        public void onCancel() {
            // App code
        }

        @Override
        public void onError(FacebookException exception) {
            // App code
        }
    });
```

And the response of the call in log is:

```
{Response:  responseCode: 200, graphObject: {"id":"896337040431723","name":"Aneh Thakur","link":"https:\/\/www.facebook.com\/app_scoped_user_id\/896337040431723\/","gender":"male","birthday":"08\/05\/1992","email":"anehkumar@gmail.com"}, error: null}
```

Hope this will help you.

- [TrinityTuts](http://trinitytuts.com)

Comment: Thanks, this is the only solution that worked in my case.

Comment: Thanks dude .. it helped me me too :)

Comment: See all parameter here https://developers.facebook.com/docs/graph-api/reference/v2.6/user

Answer (score 13):

You can get the logged user email as follows , But note that ,

1. They do not guaranteed you will get an email address [read here](https://developers.facebook.com/docs/facebook-login/permissions/v2.3#reference-public_profile) .
2. In some cases, though user has provided an email, it will not come through request, if the email is not valid.

   ```
   @Override
   public void onSuccess(LoginResult loginResult) {


   GraphRequest request = GraphRequest.newMeRequest( AccessToken.getCurrentAccessToken(),
           new GraphRequest.GraphJSONObjectCallback() {
               @Override
               public void onCompleted(JSONObject object,GraphResponse response) {
               try {
                   String  email=object.getString("email");
                   Log.d(TAG + "user email ", email);
                   } catch (JSONException e) {
                       // TODO Auto-generated catch block
                       e.printStackTrace();
                   }

               }

               });

               request.executeAsync();                        
    }
   ```

Answer (score 1):

```
fbLoginButton.setReadPermissions("public_profile", "user_friends", "user_photos", "email", "user_birthday", "public_profile", "contact_email");
```

"contact_email" is the email permission, i was missing that when i added it to i got the things working.