# Facebook API doesn't return email

Tags: java, android, facebook-graph-api, facebook-android-sdk

I know that this question has been asked, but there is only one answer pretty much or is not even answered.

I dont know if it's my lack of understanding or lack of Facebook documentation, but so far i have this code to retrieve user email.

```
callbackManager = CallbackManager.Factory.create();
    mFbLoginManager.registerCallback(
            callbackManager,
            new FacebookCallback < LoginResult > () {
                @Override
                public void onSuccess(final LoginResult loginResult) {
                    // Handle success
                    Log.i(TAG, "callBack Login Result: LoginManager success - " + loginResult.toString());
                    GraphRequest.newMeRequest(loginResult.getAccessToken(), new GraphRequest.GraphJSONObjectCallback() {
                        @Override
                        public void onCompleted(JSONObject userObject, GraphResponse response) {
                            if (response.getError() == null) {
                                try {
                                    AccessToken token = AccessToken.getCurrentAccessToken();
                                    Log.e(TAG, token.getToken());
                                    Log.e(TAG, userObject.toString());
                                    email = userObject.getString("email");
                                } catch (JSONException ex) {
                                    Log.e(TAG, "Not such permissions for email!");
                                    ex.printStackTrace();
                                }
                                Log.d(TAG, "Email fetched: " + email);
                            }else{
                                Log.e(TAG, "Something went wrong with fetching email with GraphRequest");
                            }
                        }
                    }).executeAsync();
                }
```

The JSON string returns only the name and the id, therefore my email variable is empty.

The part i am troubled with is that when i test it on Graph Explorer or with that [link](https://graph.facebook.com/me?fields=email&access_token=%3Cvalid_token%3E), i get the email.

I have se permissions also on the developers site dashboard and also in my code(that's inside onClick() when user press the facebook login button):
`mFbLoginManager.logInWithReadPermissions(LoginActivity.this, Arrays.asList("user_photos", "email", "public_profile")`

So i am not sure what is the problem in my code. The login button is custom and not the facebook LoginButton, i dont know if that matters.

Every help is welcome

Comment: check this out http://stackoverflow.com/a/32776987/2556660

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Facebook JS SDK's FB.api('/me') method doesn't return the fields i expect in Graph API v2.4+](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/32584850/facebook-js-sdks-fb-api-me-method-doesnt-return-the-fields-i-expect-in-gra) - you neglected to _ask_ for the fields you want, which is necessary since API v2.4

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Add below depandancy in Gradle

```
implementation 'com.facebook.android:facebook-android-sdk:4.11.0'




 FacebookSdk.sdkInitialize(this);
    callbackManager =CallbackManager.Factory.create();

    // -----start putting in oncreate-----------------------
    
    LoginManager.getInstance().logInWithReadPermissions(UserActivity.this, Arrays.asList("public_profile", "user_friends","email"));

    facebookTime();

    //----onclicklisterner ---------------/

            callbackManager.onActivityResult(requestCode,resultCode,data);

    //---onactivityresult-------------/

    public void facebookTime() {
        LoginManager.getInstance().registerCallback(callbackManager,
                new FacebookCallback<LoginResult>() {
                    @Override
                    public void onSuccess(LoginResult loginResult) {
                        System.out.println("Success");
                        GraphRequest request = GraphRequest.newMeRequest(
                                loginResult.getAccessToken(), new GraphRequest.GraphJSONObjectCallback() {
                                    @Override
                                    public void onCompleted(JSONObject object, GraphResponse response) {
                                        //   Util.showCenteredToast(getActivity(), "object" + object);
                                        //     Util.showCenteredToast(getActivity(), "GraphResponse" + response);
                                        try {
                                            strEmail = object.getString("email");
                                            strUserName = object.getString("name");
                                            String id = object.getString("id");
                                            // write your code here
                                            //asyncTask.iSocialMediaResponse = LoginFragment.this;
                                            asyncTask.execute();


                                        } catch (JSONException e) {
                                            e.printStackTrace();
                                        }
                                    }
                                });
                        Bundle parameters = new Bundle();
                        parameters.putString("fields", "email,name");
                        //parameters.putString("fields", "user_friends");
                        request.setParameters(parameters);
                        //Log.e(" About to Graph Call", " ");
                        request.executeAsync();
                    }
                    
                    @Override
                    public void onCancel() {
                        // App code
                        Util.showCenteredToast(UserActivity.this, "oncancel");
                    }
                    
                    @Override
                    public void onError(FacebookException exception) {
                        // App code
                        Util.showCenteredToast(UserActivity.this, "exception" + exception);
                    }
                });
    }
    
    @Override
    public void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent data) {
        super.onActivityResult(requestCode, resultCode, data);
        callbackManager.onActivityResult(requestCode, resultCode, data);

    }
```

Comment: the part that troubles me on that snippet is how to actually store the email. Plus i have to get the data after the async task is completed